# Push wildcard element of regular expression into an array

Tags: c++, regex, visual-c++, c++-cli

I am attempting to read through a bunch of code files to pull out all the parameters used in a specific function. I am reading the files to a string one at a time, I was thinking I could use regular expression with a pattern like

```
"functionName\(.*[\),]"
```

where there is the function & an overload. The first parameter is always a macro'd string, and I want to add these wildcard elements to an array
So that if it finds

```
functionName(ARGUMENT_1) or functionName(ARGUMENT_1, ....)
```

ARGUMENT_1 will be added to the array

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Functions with only one argument will be captured:

```
\w+\((\w+)\)
```

This is how you would implement it in Python. You can port this logic to C++

```py
import re

pattern = "\w+\((\w+)\)"
text = """functionName(ARGUMENT_1) or functionName(ARGUMENT_1, ....)
functionName(ARGUMENT_2) or functionName(ARGUMENT_2, ....)"""
a = re.findall(pattern,text)
print a
```

Output:

```
['ARGUMENT_1', 'ARGUMENT_2']
```

Demo on Regex101
https://regex101.com/r/cKTn4Q/2

Comment: @AlanMoore How did you do that?

Comment: You mean, how did I force Python code highlighting?  Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting).  (From the Help button at the top right corner of the edit box.)  Slightly arcane, but fully documented. :D

Comment: @AlanMoore Yeah :) I tried to make the string look like a string but could not do it. So left it like that :P. Thanks for the Tip! :)